# Launching BlackBerry and Windows Phone markets from NFC tag if application isn't installed

Tags: blackberry, windows-phone, nfc, ndef

Is there any way to launch the BlackBerry or Windows Phone markets from a NFC tag when the application isn't installed?

I mean, like AAR in Android platform, if the application that the tag is destined for isn't installed then google play store is launched.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can launch an installed Windows Phone app or **redirect to the Store if it isn't installed**:

- Put an NDEF message on the tag with a [LaunchApp record](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13539.how-to-launch-apps-via-proximity-apis-nfc.aspx) as the first record.
- Set the platform ID to "WindowsPhone"
- Set the app ID to the ID of the app (to get the app ID, just browse the web app store, the ID is at the end of the URL, e.g for Facebook the app URL is http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/facebook/82a23635-5bd9-df11-a844-00237de2db9e, the app ID is `82a23635-5bd9-df11-a844-00237de2db9e`).

This [library on Codeplex](https://ndef.codeplex.com/) that can help to create such NDEF records on Windows Phone.

Comment: Thanks Olivier, this will do it on WindowsPhone, since what version of WindowsPhone is this available? Anyone else know anything about BB?

Comment: This is available since Windows Phone 8

Comment: What if my tag is URI based for compatibility with other platforms like Android? It launches the app in windows phone but does not seem to find in the store.

Answer (score -1):

Code to receive a message from NFC tag

```
ProximityDevice device = ProximityDevice.GetDefault();

// Make sure NFC is supported
if (device!= null)
{
  long Id = device.SubscribeForMessage ("Windows.SampleMessageType", messageReceived);
  Debug.WriteLine("Published Message. ID is {0}", Id);

  // Store the unique message Id so that it 
  // can be used to stop subscribing for this message type
}

private void messageReceived(ProximityDevice sender, ProximityMessage message)
{

  Debug.WriteLine("Received from {0}:'{1}'", sender.DeviceId, message.DataAsString);
  openMarketPlace(message.DataAsString);
}
```

How To get the app ID to open the app page on the marketplace

```
private void openMarketPlace(string appID){
MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
marketplaceDetailTask.ContentIdentifier = appID;
marketplaceDetailTask.Show();
}
```